# Swift function call from class

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, viewdidload

So I have a class called `Routes` in which I have a function called `getRouteInfo()` that takes no parameters and has no return value and it is inside a Cocoa Touch class file. Then I have a `tableView controller` in which I want to call this function inside the `viewDidLoad()` method. For some reason, the compiler is forcing me to pass a parameter into it of type `Routes` even though my function is meant to not take any parameters.

The compiler is forcing me to pass a parameter inside the function :[image]

Now, when I tried passing `nil` to it, I get the following error message: `Nil is not compatible with expected argument type Routes`.

Then when I try simply calling it as `Routes.getRouteInfo()` the compiler yells at me with: `Missing argument for parameter #1 in call`

If anybody could tell me why this is happening and how to resolve it, I'll be extremely grateful.

Comment: Read about the difference between "class method" and "type method".

Comment: Show us how you defined `getRouteInfo()` method.

Comment: you need to initialize `Routes` before calling its function like `Routes().getRouteInfo()` if you want to call funtion without initializing `Routes class` then define `func getRouteInfo()` as `class func getRouteInfo()`

Comment: Thanks!! Extremely helpful